# Задать команду для cron

Tags: linux, ubuntu

подскажите как вызвать условие в команде? Мне нужно запустить процесс если он не запущен ps aux | grep geth вот так ищу процесс но нужно если ничего не найдено запустить geth

Comment: Неудачное решение. Эта команда может «грепнуть» сама себя. Такие вещи лучше делать через pid файлы.

Comment: Добавьте `|grep -v grep` и проверьте, что вывод не пуст

Comment: @avp, чем городить огород, лучше прочитать про *pgrep*.

Comment: не стоит начинать изобретать колесо. [оно уже давно придумано, реализовано и используется на практике](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/start-stop-daemon#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_pid-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: Эм... `systemd`? Или я опять недопонял условия?

Comment: @0andriy, сходу обо всем уже не вспомнить, вот и подсказываю решения 30-летней давности

Answer (score 3, accepted):

команда `ps aux | grep geth` в большинсте случаев покажет и себя. Поэтому, давно известен трюк - нужно один символ взять в квадратные скобки `ps aux | grep [g]eth`. Теперь как узнать, а нашлось ли что то. Тут есть два приема. Один (жуткий) пропустить ещё через `wc -l`. Но лучше проверить код возврата. (переменная `$?`). Если ноль - что то найдено, если 1 - ничего не найдено. 2 - случилась ошибка (например, кривая регулярка).

Но это все слишком сложно. В линуксе есть команда pgrep, которая как раз и выполняет нужную работу - грепает процессы и выводит их pid, если что то есть.

Ближе к коду

```
if pgrep geth
then
  echo "process found"
else
  echo "process not found"
  # тут код запуска процесса, наверно, нужно с nohup или &
fi
```

Предупреждение! в некоторых дистрибутивах pgrep нет из коробки. Обычно оно  есть в пакетах с именем pkill.

Comment: спасибо то, что нужно